# LinkedIn set member permission using Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I am using the standard Javascript method of signing in with a user:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="linkedInUrl">
    api_key: s4mp13
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    </script>
```

and I am unable to access a user's email field with the following call:

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
IN.API.Profile("me") // get user 
.fields(["email-address"])
.result(function (result) {
profile = result.values[0];
$.post('/User/Authorize/', { 'profile': profile }, function (data) {
window.location = data;
});
});
}
```

I take it this is because I have not specified the member permission `'r_emailaddress'`? But I have looked around and can only see examples of this with the `REST API`, how do I define the member permissions in `JavaScript`?

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution hidden away in the LinkedIn forums, scope can be defined here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="linkedInUrl">
        api_key: s4mp13
        authorize: true
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        scope: r_fullprofile r_emailaddress
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this after page load, you can do the following:

```
IN.ENV.js.scope.push('r_fullprofile');
```

And then bind the following to a click:

```
IN.User.authorize();
```

Note that IN.User.authorize only seems to prompt for new permissions once / page load.  Not sure why or if there is a work-around for that.

Also note that this is not fully documented as far as I can tell, and so it may or may not be guaranteed to work going forward...